# Keyword Search with Auto Populate Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, auto-populate, keyword-search

I have a list of bank transaction that each transaction has to be categorized. I have formulas that populate `C2:C` which works as keyword searcher.

```
A2:A are the bank transaction descriptions
C2:C are the bank transaction category
E2:E are the keyword
F2:F are the category for the keyword
```

So, the formula searches for keyword in description `A2:A` that contains keywords in `E2:E` and populates `C2:C` with the return of the corresponding category with the keyword that matches with `F2:F`.

The problem is, I have to drag down the formula each time I add a new bank description. Is there any array formula that works like keyword searcher like that but may also auto populate the cell below if I add a new bank transaction?

Here is the case:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlCSGgQaUEwIDMgEG_G9YXQGpnn99IIp9C7OGkFXYkY/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to do a little research before this, but somehow didn't find any good one, or maybe I wasn't lucky enough to find one. If anyone can help, that would be very good.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
={"category"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A2:A),
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(E:E)))), E:F, 2, 0)))}
```

[image: 0]